# How to attach excel file in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I have upload functionality in my form, which allows me to upload PDF files and documents.

When I try to upload the excel file, it returns the error **file invalid**.

How can I upload excel files?

HTML page (form) -

```
<div class="box box-default">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">HRMS Data Formate </h3>
  </div>
   <div class="box-body">
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@hrms_data_formate,html: {id: 'hrms_data_formate'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group required">       
         <%= f.text_field :name ,label: "Name"%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group required">
         <%= f.file_field :document, label: 'Upload Document' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Status</label>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.check_box :status , label:'Active'%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_area :description ,label: "Description" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="actions" style="padding: 30px">
          <%= f.submit 'Create',class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm"  %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<script>
$("#hrms_data_formate").validate({
    rules: {
      "hrms_data_formate[name]":{
        required: true,
      },
      "hrms_data_formate[document]":{
        required: true,
      },
       },
    messages: {
      "hrms_data_formate[name]":{
        required: "Please specify name",
      },
       "hrms_data_formate[document]":{
        required: "Please upload document",
      },
       },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.css({"color": "red", "font-size": "12px","font-weight" : "normal"})
     error.insertAfter(element.parent(element));
    }
   });

</script>
```

Model Code -

```
   has_attached_file :document, :path => "attachments/attach_resume/:basename.:extension"
   validates_attachment_presence :document
   validates_attachment_size :document, less_than: 15.megabytes
   validates_attachment :document, content_type: { content_type: %w(application/pdf application/msword application/msexcel application/xls application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }
```

Please help me, I am unable to upload excel file.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: is the error returned a server error? Can you paste it here

Comment: It is not a server error in front end it shows file invalid .

Comment: ohh, Can you please post your view code.

Comment: Done please check .

Comment: thanks, there is nothing in the view that points to it stopping excel files. Can you `grep -nr 'file invalid'` to see where this error might be coming from

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
     <%= f.file_field :document, html: {name: "..."}, :accept => '.doc,.docx,.pdf,.png,.xls,.xlsx,.DOC,.DOCX,.PDF,.PNG,.XLS,.XLSX' %>
```

and remove

```
 validates_attachment :document, content_type: { content_type: %w(application/pdf application/msword application/msexcel application/xls application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }
```

Comment: I tried but not working, showing an error Please enter a value with a valid mimetype.

Comment: does it give similar kind of error with different file like pdf or txt file

Comment: then may be the file is corrupted or the extension of file is wrong can you download some excel file from internet(.xls or .xlsx)  and try to upload it

Comment: thats wierd at the time of attaching the file you are getting the pop saying Please enter a value with a valid mimetype is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160065/discussion-between-yogeshmanjhi-and-anubhi-golechha).